# Database conversions?

Tags: google-app-engine, ms-access, flask, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a simple Microsoft access database and I'm about to try to move to a full data entry web app. I could either do a Flask app (possibly hosted on Google App Engine) or a Meteor-js app (looking into Galaxy and Modulus). My concern right now is: it seems like it would be straightforward enough to write a python script to run through each row of the access database and create a new entry in an Sqlite database for example; but how could I do this to move from access to app engine's NDB or Meteor's MongoDB? Also if I do this, how difficult would it be to 'export' to an access database if necessary?

**----------EDIT----------**

So to be more specific: It will hopefully be a flask app hosted on Google App Engine and in theory (or at least to my understanding) it should be simple enough to run through the access database and create new entries in a MySQL database which from my understanding is what Google's cloud datastore is based in. Can anyone walk me through the actual steps of doing this, i.e. am I oversimplifying it in my head?

Answer (score 1):

Most databases (including Mongo) have drivers that can expose row data as an ODBC driver. And also these databases have the ability to import text files (comma delimited or so called CSV in the Access world).

Since all of these database systems (including Mongo) have tools and ability to import the data, then you would simply export the data from Access and you done with Access.

As for exporting from Oracle, MySQL or Mongo (or anything else) into Access then the approach is usually the opposite of above. You simply export data as CSV and then import that data into Access.

There are few (if any) database products that can directly create an Adobe PDF file, or an Access database, or an Oracle database. So few if any products can no more create an Access database then say a MySQL database. (that’s not how the computer industry works in general).

So you can certainly export data and table data from most databases into a text format that in turn can be imported into say an Access database.

So in few cases the Oracle, or Mongo or any database system will not export to some other database, but exporting to some text format which can then be imported into the give database system is common, and usually such imports can be done without having to write code.

Also keep in mind that when referring to Access, there is a data engine part (the database) and then the application and UI part. The application part such as code, forms, reports in Access are NOT part of the database, but part of the application and it VERY VERY VERY important to distinguish between data in some tables which can be exported to another database and that of the code, forms/UI and reports which are application parts and code which MySQL or say a Oracle database does not provide. So moving the data is easy, but that does not move the code, user interface and program logic you may have created in Access.

Comment: do you have any preferred/recommended drivers?

Comment: Well, as noted, if you export to a CSV format, then you don't need any drivers and can use the import tools that come with the given database system. As for drivers, you simply have to check the MongoDB site and see if they support ODBC. If a ODBC driver is available for mongo, then you could pull and push data to the MongoDB from Access without using a intermediate format such as CSV. So don't know if Mongo supports ODBC, but it certainly supports importing (and exporting) of CSV files.